# MS access. VBA. exporting reuslts from two tables to a text file using semicolon as delimiter

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

I'm New to this forum so please be patient with me, thanks. I am not an expert in VBA. I am from Norway so my english is not the best.
I need to create a text-file generator. The text-files are beeing used as inspection reports in a pipe inspection program.

The text-file must look like this.

```
[Inspection1]  
PipeID=112  
FromPointNo=8696  
ToPointNo=8292  
Street=Trykkeriveien  
Date=30.07.2009  
Signature=Tho  
Weather=B  
PreWashed=N  
ArchiveRef=  
PipeFeature=AF  
Material=Bet  
Dimension=400  
PipeForm=S  
VerticalDim=  
PipeLength=94,24  
Comment= SM=9,6  
SD=0



Obs=Distance;Observation;Type;ClockPos;Rank;Photo;VideoPos;Comment
Obs1=0,00;SI;;;0;No;;Start inspection  
Obs2=4,38;PC;;0;1;No;;Pipe connection, from 01-12  
Obs3=11,55;PC;;2;2;No;;Pipe connection, from 00-11  
Obs4=21,21;PC;;1;1;No;;Pipe connection, from 02-12  
Obs5=22,56;FI;;;0;No;;Inspection finished
```

For solving this i have created two tables, one for the inspection and the other for the inspection details.
The difficult part is how to deal with the header (the upper part of the text-file) and the details below.
I have a built up a string that contains the header and it looks exactely like it should. BUT!!! The lower part (the part containing the oberservation details)
I have not solved. I have tried several approaches, but have not suceeded - YET.
Any suggestion on how to proceed?
Best Regards from Anders

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for `ADODB.Recordset.GetString`!!!  This method will wrap field and record values using `ColumnDelimiter` and `RowDelimiter` respectively.  It allows for fast creation of csv file and even HTML tables.

[MSDN - GetString Method (ADO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676975(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Variant = recordset.GetString(StringFormat, NumRows, ColumnDelimiter, RowDelimiter, NullExpr)

### test.txt

[image]

### test.html

[image]

```
Sub TestFile()
    Const FILEPATH = "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\stack-overflow\Inspection Reports\test.txt"
    Dim OutputString As String
    OutputString = getInspectionDetails & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & getInspection
    Open FILEPATH For Output As #1
    Print #1, OutputString
    Close #1
End Sub

Function getInspection(Optional ColumnDelimeter = ";", Optional RowDelimeter = vbCrLf) As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "[Inspection]", CurrentProject.Connection

    'RowDelimeter
    getInspection = rs.GetString(ColumnDelimeter:=ColumnDelimeter, RowDelimeter:=RowDelimeter, NullExpr:="&nbsp;")
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Function

Function getInspectionDetails(Optional ColumnDelimeter = ";", Optional RowDelimeter = vbCrLf) As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "[Inspection Details]", CurrentProject.Connection
    getInspectionDetails = rs.GetString(ColumnDelimeter:=ColumnDelimeter, RowDelimeter:=RowDelimeter, NullExpr:="&nbsp;")
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Function


Sub TestHTML()
    Const FILEPATH = "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\stack-overflow\Inspection Reports\test.html"
    Dim OutputString As String, tBody As String

    OutputString = "<!DOCTYPE html><body><table>@tablebody</table></body></html>"
    tBody = getInspection(getInspection("</td><td>", "</td></tr>" & vbCrLf & "<tr><td>"))
    tBody = "<tr>" & Left(tBody, Len(tBody) - 4)

    Open FILEPATH For Output As #1
    Print #1, Replace(OutputString, "@tablebody", tBody)
    Close #1
End Sub
```